# Is there a commercially supported option for a standalone Spring Cloud Data Flow?

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow

We're looking at using Spring Cloud Task / Spring Cloud Data Flow for our batch processing needs as we're modernising from a legacy system. We don't want or need the whole microservices offering ... we want to be able to deploy jobs/tasks, kick off batch processes, have them log to a log file, and share a database connection pool and message queue. We don't need the whole PaaS that's provided by Spring Cloud Foundry, and we don't want to pay for that, but we do want the Data Flow / Task framework to be commercially supported. Is such an option available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring Cloud Data Flow (SCDF) builds upon [spring-cloud-deployer](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-deployer) abstraction to deploy stream/task workloads to a variety of runtimes including Cloud Foundry, Kubernetes, Mesos and Yarn - see this [visual](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/#building-blocks-of-spring-cloud-data-flow).

You'd need a runtime for SCDF to orchestrate these workloads in production setting. If there's no scope for cloud infrastructure, the YARN based deployment could be a viable option for standalone bare-metal installation. Please review the [reference guide](http://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow-server-yarn/docs/1.0.2.RELEASE/reference/html/) and Apache Ambari [provisioning tools](http://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow-server-yarn/docs/1.0.2.RELEASE/reference/html/yarn-deploying-on-ambari.html) for more details. There's a separate commercial support option available for this type of installation.

Comment: Thanks, Sabby ... appreciate the help.